# How to prevent Java scanner from inputing spaces

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to prevent the user from inputting spaces or no values.
but nothing works. Even with no entered values program goes further without printing my error. What am I doing wrong?
[my code example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77D5G.png)

```
Scanner nameScan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Input your name: ");

String newcomer = nameScan.nextLine();                 
player.setName(newcomer);
String userName = player.getName();
userName = userName.trim();


if (userName.length()==0) {
     System.out.println(" ");
     System.out.println("You have to set up a player name first... ");
     System.out.println(" ");                               
}
else {...
```

Comment: If you want to prevent something from happening you have to check for it. Check that the value provides in `newcomer` is white space or not, and proceed only if it's not.

Comment: It makes sense to loop over the input until you get it right - I wrote a code example in an answer below.

Comment: FYI, you don't need to do `userName.length()==0`, you can just do `userName.isEmpty()`. Same behaviour but the second one's more readable (and you could argue 0 is a magic number here).

Answer (score 0):

As @11thdimension said, you have to validate the input.

You can do something like:

```
if (newcomer.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println("Please write something");
}
```

Or you can do a `while` loop and keep asking for a correct input.

Comment: I would use StringUtils.IsBlank() or .hasText(), as it checks for whitespaces too.

Comment: @PanBrambor `StringUtils` is not in the JDK. As a beginner, I doubt he's already including Apache Commons and it's certainly not worth including just for this task.

Comment: @Michael It is apache, or spring, but fair point, guess I'm too aclimated to this.

Answer (score 0):

Your code

```
if(username.length() == 0)
```

will not check whether the username contains space because space is counted towards the length of the String.

To check for empty String input(which may contain space(s)), you can do:

```
if("".equals(username.replaceAll("\\s+","")))   //or

if("".equals(username.trim())                   //or

if(username.isEmpty())
```

---

Further more, you would want to use a do-while loop for validation instead of using an if-statement.

Comment: "because space is counted towards the length of the String". He's already trimmed it.

Comment: And please don't suggest even `"".equals(...)`. `isEmpty` is objectively better.

Comment: @Michael and `.isEmpty(...)` has a tendency for `NullPointerException`. Each has its own pros and cons.

Comment: Simple solution: don't allow Strings to be null. All 3 of your examples might NPE.